# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2,3972E-7'---loadtxt (numpy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

This is some sample from large txt file: [0, 0, 0, 2.3972E-7, 2.3972E-6, 1.23, 100.5, 1000.78, 2012.99] and I get ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2,3972E-7'. Here is code:

```
# read the data sample
W_data = open("power.txt").read().split()
W_data1 = np.array(W_data).astype('float64')
```

Comment: ""I get ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2,3972E-7'. "" there is a comma in 2397E-7 , it should be pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that doesn't match up here is that the error message uses a decimal comma `,` while the given sample uses decimal point `.`. This typically occurs when the [locale field `LC_NUMERIC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.localeconv) has been set inappropriately or misapplied. Your code also doesn't support the sample format, so this difference is probably stored in the file, which appears to be a whitespace separated list of numbers.

Two ways to parse this:

```
import numpy as np
import locale

# Simply replace the commas with periods
numstrings = open("power.txt").read().replace(',', '.').split()
nums = np.array(numstrings).astype('float64')

# Parse according to a locale that uses decimal comma
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'sv_SE')
numstrings = open("power.txt").read().split()
nums = np.array(list(map(locale.atof, numstrings)))
```

Your default locale may well work, which you can set using `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')` or `locale.resetlocale()`. Locale may also be set by default, but some functions such as numpy's `astype` do not use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [22]: a =  [0, 0, 0, 2.3972E-7, 2.3972E-6, 1.23, 100.5, 1000.78, 2012.99]

In [25]: np.array(a).astype(np.float64)
Out[25]: array([0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00, 2.39720e-07, 2.39720e-06,
   1.23000e+00, 1.00500e+02, 1.00078e+03, 2.01299e+03])
```